# GNU Parallel | pipe command

Tags: linux, greenplum, gnu-parallel

I am completely new in using *GNU* `parallel` and I need your advice in running the command below using *GNU* `parallel`:

```
/home/admin/Gfinal/decoder/decdr.pl --gh --w14b /data/tmp/KRX12/a.bin | 
perl  /home/admin/decout/decoder/flow.pl >> /data/tmp/decodedgfile/out_1.txt
```

I will run this command on a list of files (`.bin`), so what is the best (fastest) approach to achieve that using *GNU* `parallel` noting that the output of the first part of the command (`/home/admin/Gfinal/decoder/decdr.pl --gh --w14b`) is very large (> 2 GB).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Will this work:

```
parallel /home/admin/Gfinal/decoder/decdr.pl --gh --w14b {} '|' perl  /home/admin/decout/decoder/flow.pl >> /data/tmp/decodedgfile/out_1.txt ::: /data/tmp/KRX12/*.bin
```

(If the output from `flow.pl` is more than your disk I/O can handle, try `parallel --compress`).

Or maybe:

```
parallel /home/admin/Gfinal/decoder/decdr.pl --gh --w14b {} '|' perl  /home/admin/decout/decoder/flow.pl '>>' /data/tmp/decodedgfile/out_{#}.txt ::: /data/tmp/KRX12/*.bin
```

It depends on whether you want a single output file or one per input file.

Also spend an hour walking through the tutorial. Your command line will love you for it. `man parallel_tutorial`

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer .. really appreciating your work .. one more question ... is using --pipe after ( /home/admin/Gfinal/decoder/decdr.pl --gh --w14b ) would make the process faster ?

Comment: Not understood. But try it and measure.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some great videos for gnu-parallel / parallel

Ref [youtube Part 1: GNU Parallel script processing and execution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpaiGYxkSuQ&list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1)

Here is a link from the GNU web site for platform specific information.

Ref [gnu parallel download information](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/)

> "Multiple input sources
>
> GNU parallel can take multiple input sources given on the command line. GNU 
>   parallel then generates all combinations of the input sources:
>
> parallel echo ::: A B C ::: D E F
>
> Output (the order may be different):
>
> A D
>
> A E
>
> A F
>
> B D
>
> B E
>    ............
>
> The input sources can be files:

```
parallel -a abc-file -a def-file echo"
```

Ref [GNU-Parallel-Tutorial](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html#GNU-Parallel-Tutorial)

With reference to the pipe

> Pipe capacity
>          A pipe has a limited capacity.  If the pipe is full, then a write(2)
>          will block or fail, depending on whether the O_NONBLOCK flag is set
>          (see below).  Different implementations have different limits for the
>          pipe capacity.  Applications should not rely on a particular
>          capacity: an application should be designed so that a reading process
>          consumes data as soon as it is available, so that a writing process
>          does not remain blocked.
>
> ```
>   In Linux versions before 2.6.11, the capacity of a pipe was the same
>    as the system page size (e.g., 4096 bytes on i386).  Since Linux
>    2.6.11, the pipe capacity is 65536 bytes.  Since Linux 2.6.35, the
>    default pipe capacity is 65536 bytes, but the capacity can be queried
>    and set using the fcntl(2) F_GETPIPE_SZ and F_SETPIPE_SZ operations.
>    See fcntl(2) for more information.
> ```
>
> PIPE_BUF
>          POSIX.1 says that write(2)s of less than PIPE_BUF bytes must be
>          atomic: the output data is written to the pipe as a contiguous
>          sequence.  Writes of more than PIPE_BUF bytes may be nonatomic: the
>          kernel may interleave the data with data written by other processes.
>          POSIX.1 requires PIPE_BUF to be at least 512 bytes.  (On Linux,
>          PIPE_BUF is 4096 bytes.)  The precise semantics depend on whether the
>          file descriptor is nonblocking (O_NONBLOCK), whether there are
>          multiple writers to the pipe, and on n, the number of bytes to be
>          written:

Ref [man7.org pipe](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html)

You could have a look at **fcntl** F_GETPIPE_SZ and F_SETPIPE_SZ operations for more information.

Ref  [fcntl](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html)

All the best